# Android remove Bitmap from Memory when leave activity

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, bitmap, android-memory

I am developing an app that needs a image gallery. i am at the point where i have all the images displaying in a grid view. when i touch an image i want it to open an activity with the touched image full screen, which is also working but when i go back to the grid and open another image the memory consumption keeps growing. i have tried setting the feature image to `null`, `Bitmap.recycle()` and calling `finish()` on the activity none of which seem to stop the memory consumption increasing when i open a different image.

**Open Detail Activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("image", adapter.file[position].getPath());
//Start details activity
startActivity(intent);
```

**Feature Image Activity**

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Intent intent = getIntent();
    private Bitmap featureImage;
    private ImageView featureView;
    private final String TAG ="Image Detail --";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        final String imgPath = extras.getString("image");
        final BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmapOptions.inDensity = 2;
        bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity = 1;

        featureImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, bitmapOptions );
        featureView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.featureImageView);
        featureView.setImageBitmap(featureImage);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        //featureImage = null;
        //featureView.setImageBitmap(null);
        //featureImage.recycle();
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

the memory continues to grog up to about 40MB and then drops to 32MB and cycles throgh in this pattern.

Any tipps/suggestions are welcome.

[image: memory monitor]

Comment: seems quite normal. The objects are being garbage collected as required. I would question calling Finish in your OnPause though as a simple action such as rotating your device or receiving a phone call will finish the activity.

Comment: Thanks @Kuffs. So you think there is no problem? also i will look at the `onPause()` issue. i hadnt concidered that, however my app is porterate only due to other features and i prefer returning to the home screen rether than an indivual image after the home button on the device is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not scaling the images down to fit the ImageView properly. You have two options:

1. Read and implement what's shown in [this lesson](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html). The benefits of this approach are you only use the code you need, the drawback is that it's quite a lot of work for something that should be straight forward.
2. Use a library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). It's simple to use and well supported. The drawback is that it does add many methods to your project that you otherwise wouldn't use, adding to the apk size.

Personally, whenever I've got to display an image, I use Glide!

Comment: i have tried option one and have a similar implementation that uses async task, and lru caching for my inital grid view but seems over kill for the single image page as i just want to display it and then trow it away. i will look in to option two.